# Java complex Iteration through a list array

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I want to iterate through groups of repeating numbers in a list array and do something when the group changes. My problem is when the next group contains the same number, how do I seperate the two groups? For example, I have the following numbers in an array:
`3,3,3,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,5,5,5,5,5`
There are always 3 lots of threes and ten lots of tens etc. But if I have 
`3,3,3,3,3,3` which is two groups of three I become unstuck.

One solution that (sort of) works is:

```
List<Integer> changeOfTableCell = new ArrayList<Integer>();
changeOfTableCell.add(3);
changeOfTableCell.add(3);
changeOfTableCell.add(3);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(10);
changeOfTableCell.add(5);
changeOfTableCell.add(5);
changeOfTableCell.add(5);
changeOfTableCell.add(5);
changeOfTableCell.add(5);

int startCounter=changeOfTableCell.get(0);
int counter=0;

for(int a=0; a<changeOfTableCell.size(); a++) { 

    if(startCounter==changeOfTableCell.get(counter)) { //the start of the group
        for(int i=0; i<startCounter; i++) { //print the group as per the size of the group

            System.out.println(changeOfTableCell.get(counter));
            counter=counter+1;
        }

        //move the start of the next group
        startCounter=changeOfTableCell.get(counter)
        System.out.println("Break");//do something here
    }
}
```

The counter goes to 18 which gives me an index out of bounds exception. The solution isn't obvious to me and it has been driving me crazy!

Thank you in advance.
Phil

Comment: Try looking at the value rather than iterating e.g. if [3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2] look at first value 3 (i=0) then group from i=0,1,2 next value is 3 (i=3) group i=3,4,5 next value is 2(i=6) so group i=6,7

Comment: This is a good idea, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

after your second for loop you should have an if guard to guard the last iteration. Which is the time where `counter` equals the size of the `List` because of the final iteration of the inner for loop increment the counter by 1

```
if(counter < changeOfTableCell.size()){
  startCounter=changeOfTableCell.get(counter);
}
```

or rather terminate

```
if(counter >= changeOfTableCell.size()) break;
startCounter=changeOfTableCell.get(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when the group changes, you don't need to iterate the list. The index of next value is current index + current value.

```
interface OnGroupChangeListener {
    void onChange(int oldValue, int newValue);
}

static void test(List<Integer> list, OnGroupChangeListener listener) {
    int idx = 0;
    while (true) {
        int value = list.get(idx);
        idx += value;
        if (idx >= list.size()) break;
        listener.onChange(value, list.get(idx));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3);

    test(list, new OnGroupChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(int oldValue, int newValue) {
            System.out.println(oldValue + " -> " + newValue);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks zhh (and all) your answers helped me to get off my thinking 'rail road track' and look at it from different perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

The counter goes to 18 and throws a IndexOutOfBoundsException because `counter` is keeping track of the number of elements it has iterated through. After printing out the last value in the list, `startCounter` tries to get the element at the 18th index, which doesn't exist (lists are 0-indexed). To fix it, do a conditional statement to check if `counter` is already at the 18th index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with:

```
public class CounterTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> changeOfTableCell = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    changeOfTableCell.add(3);
    changeOfTableCell.add(3);
    changeOfTableCell.add(3);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(10);
    changeOfTableCell.add(5);
    changeOfTableCell.add(5);
    changeOfTableCell.add(5);
    changeOfTableCell.add(5);
    changeOfTableCell.add(5);
    int start=0;
    int length=changeOfTableCell.get(0);


    for(int a=0; a<changeOfTableCell.size(); a++){

    for(int i=start; i<length; i++) {

        System.out.println(changeOfTableCell.get(start));

    }if(length==changeOfTableCell.size()){
        System.out.println("Do something ");break;
        }else start=length; length=length+changeOfTableCell.get(start);
            System.out.println("Do something ");
}
```

}

}